# Is there a way to push the app to heroku from different project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an private app that I was working since I started to learn Rails. But now I want to rewrite it from the ground in new project. IT will be the same up but written better. The base app is deploy and running, from  some time. And I want to preserve users and comments.

My question is: can I rewrite the project in new rails project and link it with existing heroku deploy to preserv the server data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push heroku master --force` would replace your application code. But it would be tricky to keep the same db structure and write a new app. You could download the backup of the db and then write a migration script which imports the data into the new structure.

Comment: I was thinking on the similar solariów also, Just download the db, write a load script, then eraze the old app and push new one to the same address